# Why is my Login Screen crashing?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I'm using a local login system on my app.

The point is to simply search for the username in the given database, extract the correct db entry and then compare passwords (pretty simple, right?)

However, I'm getting a force-close on my activity. Below you have the code I'm using

DB Function:

```
public Cursor loginUser(String username) throws SQLException{
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROW_ID_USER, KEY_USER_NAMES, KEY_USER_PASSWORDS, KEY_USER_ACCESS};
    String whereClause = KEY_USER_ACCESS+"='" + username+ "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.query(USERS_TABLE, columns, whereClause, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Initialising dbAdapter:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);

    dbAdapter = new PirelliDBAdapter(this);
    .......................................
```

Calling of that function:

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            username = usernameInput.getText().toString();
            password = passwordInput.getText().toString();

            Cursor c = dbAdapter.loginUser(usernameInput.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

And finally the error log:

```
03-11 01:08:25.225: W/dalvikvm(1563): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at pirelli.app.dbadapter.PirelliDBAdapter.loginUser(PirelliDBAdapter.java:391)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at pirelli.app.LoginScreen$8.onClick(LoginScreen.java:176)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11934)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-11 01:08:25.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help on this would be great. I'm really stumped and can't figure it out...

Comment: Can you post more code of the PirelliDBAdapter, and where/how it is initialised? Seems like db is probably null?

Comment: Which line is line number 391 in your dbadapter? (the line causing the nullpointer exception) Will delete this answer after clarification.

Comment: seems your db is null !!

Comment: The adapter class is over 1000 lines long and used in many other activities with success. I don't really understand how it can be null. Do you mean the table itself is null and that'll just be solved by inserting a couple of users? (Not home, can't try right now)

Comment: Also, it's initialised right after onCreate. I'll post the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **only** thing that it might be is that `db` is null, make sure you assigned a Database to it, should be like:

```
db = getReadableDatabase();
```

How to find - the last method called (in call stack) is:

```
pirelli.app.dbadapter.PirelliDBAdapter.loginUser(PirelliDBAdapter.java:391)
```

So it has to be in `loginUser` method. Now, first two lines can't be it, as you are not dereferecing anything, or calling any method on an object. Also, it can't be the last lines, as you are checking for null.

Comment: The DB is not null, it's used in other activities exactly like in this one (or...more probably I don't get how the db can be null after initalising...), and the login function is and EXACT copy-paste (replaced username) of another function that works perfectly ok...

Comment: I just got it, I changed the dbAdapter from private to public and it suddenly works.